# Regexfor removal of comma separated numbers inside square brackets

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to get specific value from the URL.

```
index.php?filter=3f-size[15],1f-colors[1],price[500,2000]&order=ASC
```

what I am trying to get price value from the URL. What I need to get is : 500,2000

What I've tried:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '/\[(.*?)\]/g').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return results[1] || 0;
    }
}
var checkedPrice = $.urlParam('price');
alert(checkedPrice);
```

Comment: `/\[(\d+(?:,\d+)*)\]/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>var results = /^.*price\[([\d,]+)\].*$/.exec("index.php?filter=3f-size[15],1f-colors[1],price[500,2000]&order=ASC")
>console.log(results[1])
 500,2000
>console.log(results[1].replace(new RegExp(",", "g"), ""))
 5002000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
\s*\[\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gjbGgP/1).

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*` - zero  or more repetitions of a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespace chars and then one or more digits
- `]` - a `]` char.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = 'index.php?filter=3f-size[15],1f-colors[1],price[500,2000]&order=ASC\nText [15, 156, 45789], some price[500, 2000]';
console.log( text.replace(/\s*\[\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*]/g, '') );
```